# how to make random operations with every dataframe element python

Tags: python, pandas

i have dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={1:[0,1,2,3,4],2:[5,6,7,8,9,]})


    1   2
0   0   5
1   1   6
2   2   7
3   3   8
4   4   9
```

so i can multiply every value for certain int, like `2`

```
df.mul(2)


     1   2
0   0   10
1   2   12
2   4   14
3   6   16
4   8   18
```

but how i can choose different random values for every value, so i can make `df.mul(np.random.randint(1,3))`

but this make one random value to all of them

i want result something like:

```
    1    2
0   0   10
1   1    6
2   2   14
3   6    8
4   8    9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining an equally shaped `np.random.randint` and with element-wise multiplication:

```
df *= np.random.randint(1,3,df.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply generate the random value and apply that to the array:

```
val = np.random.randint(1,3)
df.mul(val)
```

One operation is scalar; the other is vectorized.  You were handing a flexible notation -- a function call -- to a vectorized operator.